# Is the print() function in python considered a void function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.7

As the title says, is the print() function in python a void function?

I thought the print() function returns and prints to screen what is passed into it. Now that I think about it, it seems like it doesn't return anything and is indeed a void function. Can someone verify this for me please? Thanks in advance!

I've tried the following:

`some_variable = print()`

`print(some_variable)
 None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not return a value, which is the same as returning None.  You won't find it explicitly in the documentation as functions returning None simply omit documenting the return value.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return any value; returns `None`. you can consider as `void`

please refer[Return Value from print()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/print)

Answer (score 0):

There are no void functions in Python. Functions without explicit `return` returns `None`, an object of type `NoneType`. Try `print(type(None))` or `print(None.__class__)`

`print` prints to the text stream and doesn't return anything (returns `None`).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print