# Is there a way to return the value of the output of python code like "print('python code')" into a String or other object using PythonInterpreter

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, pythoninterpreter

I am trying to make a simple python interpreter using java. basically, you write some python code like print('hello world') and the request is sent to a spring boot back end app that interprets the code using **PythonInterpreter** library and returns the result in a JSON object form like :

```
{
  "result": "hello world"
}
```

I tried the following code that displays the result of print on the console but I wasn't able yet to assign the return into a variable that I need to construct the JSON response.

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.exec("print('hello world')");
```

prints `hello world` on the console.

I want something like this :

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.exec("x = 2+2");
PyObject x = interp.get("x");
System.out.println("x: "+x);
```

this prints `x: 4` i want to do the same with print but I still haven't found a solution.

anyone has an idea on how to do this would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Python [`print` *does not return a value.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58887963/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Returning a value isn't the only meaning of the word "output"; in this context the output is what's printed to `sys.stdout`. I'm guessing the solution involves redirecting `sys.stdout` to something else.

Comment: Perhaps, or OP could overload `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`PythonInterpreter`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html), you will find the following methods:

- [`setErr(Writer outStream)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#setErr-java.io.Writer-) - Sets a Writer to use for the standard output stream, sys.stderr.
- [`setOut(Writer outStream)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.python/jython-standalone/2.7.1/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#setOut-java.io.Writer-) - Sets a Writer to use for the standard output stream, sys.stdout.

So you would do it like this:

```java
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.setOut(out);
interp.setErr(out);
interp.exec("print('hello world')");
String result = out.toString();
System.out.println("result: " + result);
```